# How to read canvas element attribute value using selenium?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I want to read canvas element value ***("Answer:5015")*** but attribute value does not exist. Can you please let me know how to read attribute value ?

App URL : https://the-internet.herokuapp.com/challenging_dom#edit

[image]

Comment: Here's a hint canvas.strokeText('Answer: 45396',90,112) .

Comment: We had the same idea @arundeep chohan. Nice one!

Answer (score 1):

This code works, using Java and Edge browser:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.edge.driver", "msedgedriver.exe");

    WebDriver driver = new EdgeDriver();
    
    driver.get("https://the-internet.herokuapp.com/challenging_dom#edit");      
    
    String answer = new String();
    
    ArrayList<WebElement>scripts = new ArrayList<WebElement>((ArrayList<WebElement>) driver.findElements(By.tagName("script")));
    
    for(int i = 0; i < scripts.size(); i++) {
        
        String focusText = scripts.get(i).getAttribute("innerHTML");
        
        if(focusText.contains("canvas.strokeText")) {

                answer = focusText.substring(focusText.indexOf("Answer"), focusText.indexOf("',"));
                
                break;
                
        }
    }
    
    System.out.println(answer);
```

Comment: I don't know, i've never used it. Sorry.